# placing article and section next to eachother: display inline block not working

Tags: html, css

On the front page of my site I want to put a brief description of what the site offers with next to that a brief description. So I decided to use an article tag for the former and a section for the latter. I though a display: inline-block would do the trick to place them next to eachother but alas that does not seem to be the case. (any better suggestions on how to do this would be welcome, I am a bit disappointed that CSS3 didn't add a clean, cross platform approach as far as I can tell)

```
<body>
        <style>

            #description{
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: 410px;
            }


            #register{
                display: inline-block;
                width:400px;
            }


        </style>
        <section>
            <article id="description">
               lorem ipsum est 
            </article>
            <section id="register">
                registrationform
            </section>
        </section>

    </body>
```

Comment: Try giving 'inline-block' style to the section ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, at least if your container (or the window) is wide enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/9V8qP/

Comment: Weird, my container is 90% of the resolution and my screen resolution is 1680*1050 so more than sufficient.